# Is "Mr Puzzle Wants You to Be Less Alive" a Netflix production?

Tags: horror, netflix, parody

I've seen [several](https://bloody-disgusting.com/videos/3686907/mr-puzzles-bot-watched-400000-hours-horror-movies-wrote-short-netflix-video/) [articles](https://nerdist.com/article/netflix-bot-written-horror-movie/) [claim](https://best-of-netflix.com/netflix-releases-its-first-ever-bot-written-horror-film/) that *[Mr Puzzle Wants You to Be Less Alive](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WZzbxNoMjGM)* is an official Netflix release done in conjunction with [Keaton Patti](https://twitter.com/KeatonPatti).

> Netflix explains, “We worked with Keaton Patti to make a bot watch over 400,000 hours of horror movies and then write its own horror movie. This is what it came up with.”
>
> The result is the 4-minute “First Horror Movie Written Entirely By Bots” video, a very Saw-like horror movie centered on Mr. Puzzles, a villain who wears a devil mask and forces his victims into elaborate traps involving everything from chair saws to a deadly rollerblade canon.

Given this short film doesn't seem to show up on Netflix.com, and the YouTube channel it comes from is named "Netflix is a Joke", I'm 90% certain that either these news sites were duped in, or that they're entirely in on the joke, but it's possible that Netflix actually did work with Mr. Patti.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Netflix is a Joke](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCObk_g1hQBy0RKKriVX_zOQ) seems to be an official Netflix YouTube channel for NF comedic content as the notes say...

> About Netflix Is A Joke: The official hub of Netflix stand-up, comedy series, films, and all things funny — curated by the world’s most advanced algorithm and a depressed, yet lovable, cartoon horse. Their unlikely friendship is our story…

As such it seems that the show IS an official Netflix production.

It's highly unlikely that such a channel would be permitted to continue with the content that is has without being an official offshoot of the media group so named.